# Use of Frame Layout in a project

Tags: android, android-layout

there are many question about **"FrameLayout**". But i need the exact use of this different from  **LinearLayout, RelativeLayout**. And in a project when we have to use this?

Answer (score 0):

**FrameLayout** is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.

**LinearLayout** arranges elements side by side either horizontally or vertically(rows vs columns).

**RelativeLayout** is a layout manager that helps you arrange your UI elements based on some rule. You can specify thisngs like: align this to parents left edge, place this to the left/right of this elements etc.

Check these links

http://logc.at/2011/10/18/when-to-use-linearlayout-vs-relativelayout/

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html